Illegal Invocation error with FormData when using shorthand post in AJAX Request
I'm encountering the error "Illegal invocation" when attempting to use the shorthand syntax for sending form data with a file upload in an AJAX request using jQuery. However, the error disappears when I use the longer .ajax() method. I'm using CodeIgniter as the server-side framework.
What's the reason for the error with the shorthand syntax, and why does the .ajax() method work?
form
<form id="add_category_form" action="<?= base_url("CategoriesController/process_add_category") ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>" value="<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>" />
    <h2>Add a Category</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="name" required>
            <label>Category Name</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <textarea name="description" required></textarea>
            <label>Description</label>
        </li>
        <label>Upload Images (5 Max)</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="category_image" accept="image/*">
    </ul>
    <!-- FIXME: center the content of this last li tag -->
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

Using $.post
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_category_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let url = $(this).attr("action");

    if ($("#category_image").val() == "") {
      alert("Please add an image");
    } else {
      let formData = new FormData(this); // Pass the form element

      $.post(url, formData, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        csrfName = response.csrfName;
        $("input[name='<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>']").val(response.newCsrfToken);
      }, "json");
    }
    return false;

using $.ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_category_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#category_image").val() == "") {
      alert("Please add an image");
    }

    let formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?= base_url(''); ?>CategoriesController/process_add_category",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        csrfName = response.csrfName;
        $("input[name='<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>']").val(response.newCsrfToken);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error("AJAX Error:", status, error);
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});


You can't use a FormData object for the data when using the shorthand version of $.post(). The documentation says that the second argument must be either a plain object or a string, not FormData.
You need to use a settings object just like $.ajax() so you can specify processData: false. Without this option, it tries to convert the object to a URL-encoded string.
